# What is this plant with the unusual Leaf

Tags: identification

[image]

We live in NSW Australia and was given this plant by a friend, very unusual.

Comment: Please send a few better pictures?  I am seeing a pot of soaked soil?  Have you fertilized?  What type and intensity of lighting does this plant need? Do you know if your friend fertilized?  What type of medium has this plant been having to live within?  Potting soil I hope?  Better picture we'll be able to give you a closer ID but with soaked soil, garden soil in the pot, no fertilizer this plant is on a diminishing life line.  Please tell us more and send a better picture or two!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Calathea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calathea), originally native to Central and South America.  There are many varieties and species as you can see from the picture below. I cannot identify which variety due to the picture quality.

Provide filtered high light and water less in the winter.  Apply dilute fertilizer in the spring.  Propagate this plant by dividing the existing plant into two.
[image: Various Calathea leaves]